# Grabbing Excess Space Equally

Tags: java, layout, swt

When using "Grab Excess Horizontal Space" on multiple SWT controls within the same space, the default behavior does not divide the space between them exactly equally.  Some sort of behind-the-scenes calculation seems to be done to divide it "sort of" equally, but giving a higher ratio to larger controls.

[image: Example Image]

In my example here, I have created a custom table-like control using grid layouts in which the user can add any number of rows, as well as any number of boxes (custom canvases) for each row individually.  My intent is to have all boxes within a given row be of equal size - and by that virtue, all rows with an equal number of boxes will have equally-sized boxes, despite being separate.  In my example, however, you can see that the one box that has label text within it grabs more space than those on the same row, due to the calculation believing that it "needs more" than the others.

What would be the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: What Layout are you using?

Comment: @Funtik I am using GridLayout, which I use for pretty much everything.  I will clarify that.

Comment: hmmm.. and you obviously tried makeColumnsEqualWidth from that layout?

Comment: @Funtik Not so obvious, I have not noticed such a thing.  That sounds like a potential answer, though, going by name alone.

Comment: OK :) will post it as an answer

Comment: A suggested read: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). Every SWT developer should have read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`makeColumnsEqualWidth`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridLayout.html#makeColumnsEqualWidth) from [`GridLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridLayout.html).

Comment: This looks exactly correct.  Although I must say, for being so simple, it was not at all obvious.  I was not able to find anything on the subject with Google searches, and I suppose I overlooked the variable in the documentation.  Very convenient that you just knew that off the top of your head!  Good show, sir.

Comment: @SouthpawHare glad that helped. Sometimes you can spend hours on making SWT layout "right".

Comment: Would API reference be a better place to start?

Comment: @Baz Maybe this sounds dumb, but... I didn't really know it had anything to do with Grid Layout, or any specific type of layout, really.  I only use Grid, not due to style, but to ignorance.  I just know that it's "really good."

Comment: @SouthpawHare Fair enough. Think about it this way: Everything that has to do with arrangement, positioning and size of components comes down to layouts.